# Why Do I LOSE Points Every Time I Make a Bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

This is a problem that I have been getting every time I have given some of my questions a Bounty.  But instead of GAINING points, as I thought a Bounty should, I LOSE them.  What is going on?

Comment: Just in case: You are aware that a bounty means that you give out some of your own rep (bounty amount) to whomever you eventually award that bounty, right?

Comment: Putting a bounty on a question is the same as advertising in real-life: you pay something to get more attention.

Answer (score 15):

Have you looked in the help menu? [This page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) discusses what a bounty is.

When you write a question, but for whatever reason aren't satisfied with the answers you get, you can start a bounty. The bounty is a reward you give using your own reputation to the user that answers your question. Users are enticed to answer the question because if they do, they might receive the reward. In exchange, you get the answer you wanted.

If you want to gain reputation, go to the [featured questions page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) and answer one of the questions. If you answer it well, the person who started the bounty might reward you with the bounty amount.

For more information, see the help page I linked to above.

Answer (score 4):

If you didnt lose something from this you could just add bounties to all of your questions to get them in the spotlight. this tool is meant to be used for people who desperately need answers and cant get them any other way.

Comment: Not only. Bounties can also be used to, for example, reward existing answers that one feels are very good.

Comment: It's not about desperation.  In addition to @cvn 's point, there are plenty of reasons for a bounty.  You might find it an interesting question and want to see what others come up with (you can be the OP or not).  You might have asked a question that requires a bit of time to answer and you want to encourage people to take that time.  And so on.